# Fscanf to read a mixture of float and characters in c

Tags: c, file, scanf

So I have a .txt file which is as following:

```
** Paris ** Flight,5 days,visiting various monuments. | 2999.99 |
** Amsterdam ** By bus,7 days, local art gallery. | 999.99 |
** London ** Flight,3 days,lots of free time. | 1499.99 |
```

I want to get the information stored into 3 variables, city, description and price, but I can't get it to save the lines at all.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char city[256],desciption[256];
    float temp;
    if(fp=fopen("Ponuda.txt","rt")==NULL){
        printf("ERROR\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(fscanf(fp,"** %s ** %s | %f |",city,description,&temp)==3){

        printf("** %s ** %s |%f|\n",city,description,temp);
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: `%s` only reads 1 word. You can't use it to read the whole description.

Comment: You'll also have a problem with cities that are more than 1 word, like `New York`.

Comment: I see, seems that  I got the wrong approach then.

Comment: Use `fgets` followed by `strtok` to split each line with the delimiter string `"*|"`. Then use `strdup` to copy the two text strings, and `sscanf` to extract the fare from the third token.

Comment: How does c see when the word ends? Couldn't I somehow make it so that the whole description is one word and that the reading stops at the character ' * '?

Comment: Functions from `scanf` family, read string until they reach whitespace (space, tab, newline).

Comment: Thought so, can I somehow bypass that, for example make it so that it doesn't stop at whitespace but at some other character? Also thanks Weather Vane, trying it right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO it is much easier to read each file line with `fgets`, and then use `strtok` to split each line with the delimiter string `"*|"`.

Then I use `strdup` to duplicate the text strings into the struct, and `sscanf` to extract the fare from the third token. I should have tested the return value from `strdup`, as it calls `malloc` internally.

I also use `double` instead of `float` (which I will only use if there are constraints).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX  10

typedef struct {
    char *city;
    char *descrip;
    double fare;
} flight_t;

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    flight_t visit[MAX] = {0};
    char buffer [1024];
    char *tok;
    int records = 0, i;
    if((fp = fopen("Ponuda.txt", "rt")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp) != NULL) {
        if((tok = strtok(buffer, "|*")) == NULL) {
            break;
        }
        if(records >= MAX) {
            printf("Too many records\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        visit[records].city = strdup(tok);          // add NULL error checking

        if((tok = strtok(NULL, "|*")) == NULL) {    // pass NULL this time
            break;
        }
        visit[records].descrip = strdup(tok);       // add NULL error checking

        if((tok = strtok(NULL, "|*")) == NULL) {    // pass NULL this time
            break;
        }
        if(sscanf(tok, "%lf", &visit[records].fare) != 1) {     // read a double
            break;
        }
        records++;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    // print the records
    for(i = 0; i < records; i++) {
        printf("** %s ** %s |%.2f|\n", visit[i].city, visit[i].descrip, visit[i].fare);
    }

    // free the memory given by strdup
    for(i = 0; i < records; i++) {
        free(visit[i].city);
        free(visit[i].descrip);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
**  Paris  **  Flight,5 days,visiting various monuments.  |2999.990000|
**  Amsterdam  **  By bus,7 days, local art gallery.  |999.990000|
**  London  **  Flight,3 days,lots of free time.  |1499.990000|
```

Comment: The one thing I don't understand is the delimiter "|*", how does that work?

Comment: I suggest you read the [`strtok` man page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8d19sb.aspx). It is a *set* of characters, any of which will break the string, in any combination.

Comment: Yes I understand but wouldn't it break the string on the first two "**"? How about if the format was:  -> Paris -> Flight,5 days,visiting various monuments. \$ 2999.99 \$ What would I use here as the limiter? (my guess is "->\$")

Comment: You would need to "escape" the '\\'. (two of them). Note that the delimitor string is not a sequence, it is a set of characters, so any single `-` in the text would break it.

Answer (score 1):

This is very difficult to do with a single fscanf statement, since, as @Barmar pointed out, the city name may be more than one word. It is much easier to read the entire line (using fgets) and then parsing the line yourself. To parse it:

1. Find the first non-blank character after "**"
2. Find the last non-blank character after that, that precedes " **'
3. The text between those indices will be the city name (it may contain spaces)
4. The description is the text between the " **" found in step 2, and the index of the next '|' after that.
5. The cost is the string following that '|'